# BigCommerce API - put customers/id updates the date_created field

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I'm updating a specific user using a put, and instead of updating the `date_modified` field to the current time it updates the `date_created` field.

The fields which I'm trying to update (`email`, `name`, `customer_group_id`) are being updated correctly.

I have tested this using both the Ruby API as well as a curl request, and it happened both times.  I think it's safe to say this is a problem on receiving the put request on BigCommerce's end.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, just verified it. The date_modified field stays blank. It is surely a bug.